# $M^G$=$\mathbb{F}_2[x_1\cdot v, x_1^2+ v]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G=Sl_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $M= \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2]$.

$M$ is a $G$-module with $(A\cdot x_1, A\cdot x_2)=(x_1,x_2)\cdot A, (\forall) A \in Sl_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

I have to show that

$M^G$=$\mathbb{F}_2[x_1\cdot v, x_1^2+ v]$,

where $v=x_2\cdot(x_1+x_2)$ and $M^G=\lbrace m\in M| g\cdot m= m, \forall g\in G\rbrace$.

In general, how can I guess  the equality?

It's easy to prove ''$\supseteq$''.

Comment: What are $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @MarcBogaerts Variables in the polynomial ring $\Bbb F_2[x_1,x_2]$. They are treated as coordinate basis vectors of $\Bbb F_2^2$ when ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F_2)$ acts on it.

Comment: Crossposted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279197/how-to-show-mg-mathbbf-2x-1-cdot-v-x-12-v).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo).

Comment: $G$ permutes the linear polynomials $x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2$ faithfully. Because $|G|=6$ all the permutations occur (my favorite way of showing that $G\simeq S_3$). Not sure about how to best use this to answer the question :-( May be Galois theory on the field of fractions $K=\Bbb{F}_2(x_1,x_2)$ using the fact that $[K:K^G]=|G|=6$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Galois theory compute the Galois group. Here I can't see a Galois extension.